# Backbone.js + Require.js: Collection URL set, but getting error "Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone.js-collections

I am currently working on the framework for a project that we have split into a web client and server code.
The client code uses a combination of require .js and backbone.js.
I'm currently working on setting up the client/server communication, and ideally we'd like to be able to use backbone’s built in .sync functionality (and the fetch call built off of it) .

However, I'm running into an odd series of errors.

As the code executes, I'm getting the following error in the console. "Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified"

These are the related shims from our main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jQueryBase': '../vendor/jquery-1.10.2/jquery-1.10.2',
        'jQuery': '../vendor/jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery-ui',
        'underscore': '../vendor/underscore/underscore',
        'backbone': '../vendor/backbone/backbone',
        'handlebars': '../vendor/handlebars/handlebars-v1.1.2 '
    },
    shim: {
        'jQuery': {
            exports: '$',
            deps: ['jQueryBase']
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            exports: 'Backbone',
            deps: ['underscore', 'jQueryBase']
        },
        'handlebars': {
            exports: 'Handlebars'
        }
    },
    waitSeconds: 0
});
```

This is our dogModel.js

```
define(['backbone'],
    function (Backbone) var DogModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    });

    return DogModel;
});
```

This is our dogCollection.js

```
define {
    ('backbone',
        '../models/dogModel'
        J,
        function (Backbone,
            DogModel) {

            var DogCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: DogModel,
                url: '/dogs',
            });

            return DogCollection;
        });
```

This is our dogData.js

```
define(['../collections/dogCollection',
        '../models/dogModel'
    ],
    function (DogCollection,
        DogModel) {

        var dogDataModule = {};

        dogDataModule.dogList = new DogCollection();

        //this request works
        $.ajax(
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost:7001/SERVICES/dogs",
            success: function (data) {
                dogDataArray = data;

                for (var i = 0; i < dogDataArray.length; i++) {
                    var dogData = dogDataArray[i];
                    var dogModel = new DogModel();
                    dogModel.set(dogData);
                    dogDataModule.dogList.add(dogModel);
                }
            }
        });

    //this request doesn't
    dogDataModule.dogList.sync('read', DogCollection, {
            success: function () {
                alert("success ");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("failure ");
            }
        };

        return dogDataModule;
    });
```

I've attempted to add a URL to directly to the options of the sync request, as so:

```
dogDataModule.dogList.sync('read', DogCollection, {
        url: 'http://localhost:7001/SERVICES/dogs',
        success: function () {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("failure "
            };
        });
```

But all this does is change the error to read "Uncaught TypeError : Object function (){ return
parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'trigger'".

I've also attempted to add "SERVICES/" and "../SERVICES/" in front of the collection's url property, or giving the full and explicit URL property (up to and including http://), but none of that has worked either.

Can anyone help me figure out why I am seeing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't think there's any reason for you to call `dogList.sync` directly (you could use `dogList.fetch`, you certainly want the features `fetch` offers you in addition to the server call.

Now, your error comes from the fact that you use `sync` incorrectly. The second argument is intended to be an instance of a collection, not a class, as shown in `fetch`'s code:

```
return this.sync('read', this, options);
```

So in your case, that'd be:

```
dogDataModule.dogList.sync('read', dogDataModule.dogList
```

Bonus:

The error `Uncaught TypeError : Object function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'trigger` comes from the fact that Backbone's trying to apply the method `trigger` of your class instead of an instance. The `function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }` part is the constructor of your class, so that gives you a hint of what's happening.

Comment: Thank you.  I used dogDataModule.dogList instead of DogCollection, and I no longer see error messages, I also got a success alert from the call, and can verify that the data I'm trying to pass back is in the array.  Your explanation was clear, concise, and easy to understand.  I'm aware that fetch is simpler, but other than that I'm unsure what else it gives me above and beyond sync that I might want to take advantage of.  I'll look into it further, but if you could give me some examples, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Well, fetch will automatically create your models based on the server's response, you won't have to do anything (Backbone will use the model property of your collection to populate it). You can always check Backbone's code to have a better idea of what the methods do, it's pretty understandable (especially the annotated source code).

Comment: Thank you.  Also, it turns off the data array I was seeing was from a different source in the non-simplified code.  I'll be looking into why I'm not actually getting an array response back, and then look into converting this into a fetch command.

Comment: This should be as simple as using `dogDataModule.dogList.fetch()` :)

Comment: It was indeed.  I switched out ".sync('read', dogDataModule.dogList", switching in ".fetch(" and it started working.  I still don't entirely get why this worked though.  Is it the line "if (!model.set(model.parse(resp, options), options)) return false;"?  I have some more digging to do to confidently understand the code I'm working with.

Comment: Ah, I think I have it.  (darn the no carriage return formatting on comments).  "collection[method](resp, options);" Activates the set method on the collection, using the response (and any options), as per http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set while if I wanted to to actually use the response back from the server and still use sync, I'd need to pass the response into my success function, and use parse on it myself.